# Is there a more efficient way of updating values in the Database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-4

What I'm doing is checking every Input tag if its empty or not, if not empty call the function, Im just wondering if there is a better way to do this

```
        $firstname = $this->request->getPost('firstname');
        $lastname = $this->request->getPost('lastname');
        $middlename = $this->request->getPost('middlename');
        $address = $this->request->getPost('address1') . $this->request->getPost('address2');
        $idNum = $this->request->getPost('idNum');
        $department = $this->request->getPost('department');
        $driverNumber = $this->session->get('driverNumber');

        if (!empty($firstname)) {
            $r = $this->db->editInfo('firstname', $firstname, $driverNumber);
        }
        if (!empty($lastname)) {
            $r = $this->db->editInfo('lastname', $lastname, $driverNumber);
        }
        if (!empty($middlename)) {
            $r = $this->db->editInfo('middlename', $middlename, $driverNumber);
        }
        if (!empty($this->request->getPost('address1')) || !empty($this->request->getPost('address2'))) {
            $r = $this->db->editInfo('address', $address, $driverNumber);
        }
        if (!empty($department)) {
            $r = $this->db->editInfo('department', $department, $driverNumber);
        }
        if (!empty($idNum)) {
            $r = $this->db->editInfo('idNum', $idNum, $driverNumber);
        }
```

I tried Switch cases but from what I understand switch cases needs a variable to equal to a string

```
$favcolor = "red";

switch ($favcolor) {
  case "red":
    echo "Your favorite color is red!";
    break;
  case "blue":
    echo "Your favorite color is blue!";
    break;
  case "green":
    echo "Your favorite color is green!";
    break;
  default:
    echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
}
```

Comment: While it's not the most elegant way, there's nothing wrong with doing things the way you are. It's readable and easy to understand what the code is doing. I did notice there is a syntax error in the `if` condition where you are checking the address. You need seperate `empty` functions for both address1 and address2.

Comment: Thank you for your Input Jacob will update the `if` condition for address

Comment: you need to create an array and update the record at once

Comment: If you allow your database to accept empty values (i.e. NULL) then you don't need to check if your data is empty. Then you can use set() or update() (depending on how your model is configured) and update with an array of the data values.

Answer (score 0):

You could add each of the variables to an array, cycle the array to check if any are empty, if all are present, perform the if statements, else, error out.

```
$fields = array($firstname, $lastname, $middlename, $address, $idNum, 
$department, $driverNum);

foreach ($fields as $field) {
if ($field) {
// db calls
} else {echo "empty field"}`;
}
```

You could also do this associatively to indicate which key is empty.

```
$fields = array("firstname" => $firstname, "lastname" => $lastname, 
"middlename" => $middlename, "address" => $address, "id" => $idNum, 
"department" => $department, "driverNo" => $driverNum);

foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
if ($value)
//db calls
} else {echo  $key . "is empty"}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Originally deleted my answer because I felt it may be problematic with the address db call. Added it back just in case it's of any use.

Answer (score 0):

Create Model **/app/Models/Model_name.php** & define update function:

```
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;
use CodeIgniter\Database\ConnectionInterface;
class Model_name extends Model {

    protected $db;
    public function __construct(ConnectionInterface &$db) {
        $this->db =& $db;
    }

    public function update($id, $data) {
        return $this->db
                        ->table('user')
                        ->where(["driverNumber" => $id])
                        ->set($data)
                        ->update();
    }
}
```

In Your controller:

1. Call a Model in Controller
2. Initailize constructor
3. Use Model to update data

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\Model_name; //Call a Model in Controller

class User extends BaseController {

  public function __construct() {    
      $db = db_connect();
      $this->Model_name= new Model_name($db);  //Update your model name
  }

  public function update() {
    $firstname = $this->request->getPost('firstname');
    $lastname = $this->request->getPost('lastname');
    $driverNumber = $this->session->get('driverNumber');

    $data = [
      'firstname'    => $firstname,
      'lastname'     => $lastname,
    ];

    $result = $this->Model_name->update($driverNumber, $data);
  }
}
```